# Hosts file is not editable, even as root user

Tags: macos, file-permissions

I am trying to edit my hosts file on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4. I've tried all the Terminal trickery I can, but I always get "Operation not permitted" when attempting to modify the file. I've tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/hosts
sudo chmod nouchg /etc/hosts
sudo cp ~/hosts /etc/hosts
```

All fail with "operation not permitted" messages. Here's the output of `ls -lO@e /etc/hosts`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  uappnd,nodump,opaque 2073 Sep 22  2010 /etc/hosts
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to read most of that. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user append-only flag is set.  Run

`sudo chflags nouappnd /etc/hosts`

and you should be able to edit and save the file as the superuser.

Comment: And for that matter, why are the nodump and opaque flags set?

Answer (score 1):

Do not change any permissions to hosts.

To use vi to edit the file:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Enter your password and you can edit and save.

Comment: That won't work.  The `uappend` flag only allows the file to be appended to.  Even root cannot overwrite the file when this flag is set.

Comment: It works with 10.6.8.  Is the uappend flag new to 10.7?

Comment: No, those file flags are very old.  They were inherited from FreeBSD, which inherited them from 4.4BSD.  Probably the earliest Mac OS X releases had them, certainly 10.4-10.7 do.  The question is why `uappend` was set on /etc/hosts.  It isn't set on my 10.7.4 Lion (Server) installation.  Neither it nor `opaque` nor `nodump` make sense there, except perhaps in a virtual machine context.